# PHP variable defined outside callback function is unaccessible inside the function

Tags: php, variables, scope

I'm trying to use `$variable` inside my callback function. I pass it to another function like this: `functionName("egTraders_ItemDataBound")`, inside that function I assign it to a variable and the call it like this: `$theAssignedFunctionVariable($this, $rowToAdd);`
And the function `egTraders_ItemDataBound` gets called properly but the variable `$variable`
is undefined. What can I do?

```
<?php

$variable = "var";
function egTraders_ItemDataBound($sender, $param1)  {
    echo $variable;
}

?>
```

Comment: can you post the other functions also? or better, the whole code.

Answer (score 10):

If You are running PHP 5.3+ You can achive this by simply creating anonymous functioin with use keyword ( [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) ) :

```
$bar = 'bar';
$f = function() use ($bar)
{
    var_dump($bar);
};

function bar( $fName )
{
    $fName();
}

bar($f);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could pass it in as a param or you could use it as a global in the function. I do not recommend the latter. You should stay away from globals.

**Edit for example**

```
$variable = "var";
function egTraders_ItemDataBound($sender, $param1) {
    global $variable;
    echo $variable;
}
egTraders_ItemDataBound(NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: even if I declare it as global $variable; $variable = 4; it's still undefined. And i'm really dissapointed with php every normal programming language would allow a use of that without problem...

Comment: what is the syntax to use it as a global?

Comment: At this point I can only say that something is wrong with the code. I've tested it and it works fine. I edited my post to contain the test I did.

Comment: I guess that the problem comes from that, that the callback is called inside another class and $variable is not in its global scope either...

Comment: Well if $variable is defined before the class is initiated it should still work. If $variable is defined within a class and you are using this callback from another classs then it wouldn't work. If that is the case, why not make it a class property and access it $class->variable or a better method of $class->getVariable()

Comment: I'm using codeigniter maybe that is the issue... because the class that is loading the view is the controler... I will make it able to pass parameters that will be passed later to the callback

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the variable as `global` because it is out of scope

```
$variable = "var";
   function egTraders_ItemDataBound($sender, $param1)  {
            global $variable;
                   echo $variable;
                }
```

Comment: Check it again. With the global $variable should now work. Although I would still say do not use globals...

Comment: make sure you initialize the `$variable` prior to the call `functionName("egTraders_ItemDataBound")`

Answer (score 0):

The variable is declared outside of the scope of the function. You should revisit your design. I strongly recommend against using global variables as that is poor practice.